# Mongo query not giving exact results for aggregate function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My mongo database contains a collection 'Shops' and the data is like below:

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("XXXX1b83d2b227XXXX"),
        "ShopId" : 435,
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "productId" : "1234",
                "productName" : "non veg",
                "productCategory" : "meals",
                "mrp" : "38",
            }, 
             {
                "productId" : "5234",
                "productName" : "non veg",
                "productCategory" : "meals",
                "mrp" : "38",
            }, 
             {
                "productId" : "6234",
                "productName" : "apple",
                "productCategory" : "juice",
                "mrp" : "38",
            }, 
             {
                "productId" : "7234",
                "productName" : "non veg",
                "productCategory" : "biriyani",
                "mrp" : "38",
            }, 
             {
                "productId" : "8234",
                "productName" : "non veg",
                "productCategory" : "biriyani",
                "mrp" : "38",
            } 
           ]
    }
```

There will be several shops in the collection having a list of products.

**Expected Output**

```
   { "productList": [
      {
        "categoryname": "meals",
        "productcount": "2",
        "products": [
          {
            "productname": "Non-Veg"
          },
           {
            "productname": "Veg"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryname": "juice",
        "productcount": "1",
        "products": [
          {
            "productname": "apple"
          }
        ]
      },{......}
     ]
}
```

I tried it using 'async' method with 2 queries, but I didn't get the output correctly. I think it can be done in one query without using 'async'.

My code follows, I think it's the wrong approach:

```
model.Shops.aggregate([
    {$match:{ShopId:435}},
    {$unwind:"$products"},
    {$limit:2},{$skip:0},
    {$group:{_id:{"productCategory":"$products.productCategory"}}}
],function (err, doc) {
        if  (doc!=null){
            var arr = [];
            async.each(doc, function(item,callback){
                model.Shops.aggregate([
                    {"$unwind":"$products"},
                    {$match:{"ShopId":435,"products.productCategory":item._id.productCategory}},
                    {$limit:2},
                    {
                        $group: {
                            _id:null,
                            "products": {
                                $push:{"productName":"$products.productName"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ], function (err,doc) {
                    arr.push({"categoryname":item._id.productCategory,"products":doc.products});
                    callback(null);
                });
            },function (err) {
                res.json(arr);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly do not need two queries for this, a single pipeline will suffice. Run the following aggregate operation to get the desired results:

```
model.Shops.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "ShopId": 435 } },
    { "$unwind": "$products" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$products.productCategory",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "products": { 
                "$push": {
                    "productName": "$products.productName"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,            
            "productList": { 
                "$push": {
                    "categoryname": "$_id",
                    "productcount": "$count",
                    "products": "$products"
                }
            }
        }
    }      
], function (err, results) {
    res.json(results);
});
```

---

### Explanations

The above pipeline uses the following pipeline steps (in the order given) and explained as:

**Step 1)** **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator is there to filter documents that get into the pipeline. If you are coming from a SQL background, this pipeline is similar to the SQL's `WHERE` clause where e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM Shops
WHERE ShopId = 435
```

If you run the pipeline at this stage only, it will return all the documents that match on the `ShopId` of 435

**Step 2)** **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** - The `products` field is an array so you'll need to add an **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** stage to your pipeline so that you can flatten the array as it needs to be processed further down as a denormalised field. For each input document, this outputs `n` documents where `n` is the number of array elements and can be zero for an empty array.

Running the aggregate pipeline up to this stage for the above sample will produce 5 documents i.e. in mongo shell

```
db.getCollection('shops').aggregate([
    { "$match": { "ShopId": 435 } }, // Step 1
    { "$unwind": "$products" }      // Step 2
])
```

will yield

```
[    
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58aadec0671a3794272f342f"),
        "ShopId" : 435,
        "products" : {
            "productId" : "1234",
            "productName" : "non veg",
            "productCategory" : "meals",
            "mrp" : "38"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58aadec0671a3794272f342f"),
        "ShopId" : 435,
        "products" : {
            "productId" : "5234",
            "productName" : "non veg",
            "productCategory" : "meals",
            "mrp" : "38"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58aadec0671a3794272f342f"),
        "ShopId" : 435,
        "products" : {
            "productId" : "6234",
            "productName" : "apple",
            "productCategory" : "juice",
            "mrp" : "38"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58aadec0671a3794272f342f"),
        "ShopId" : 435,
        "products" : {
            "productId" : "7234",
            "productName" : "non veg",
            "productCategory" : "biriyani",
            "mrp" : "38"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58aadec0671a3794272f342f"),
        "ShopId" : 435,
        "products" : {
            "productId" : "8234",
            "productName" : "non veg",
            "productCategory" : "biriyani",
            "mrp" : "38"
        }
    }
]
```

**Step 3)** **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step to group the documents in the pipeline by the `productCategory` field from the denormalised documents and creates an array `products` that has fields from the previous pipeline. The **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline operator is similar to the SQL's `GROUP BY` clause.

In SQL, you can't use `GROUP BY` unless you use any of the aggregation functions. The same way, you have to use an aggregation function called accumulator in MongoDB as well. You can read more about the aggregation functions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator).

The accumulator operator you would need to create the array is **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)**.

In the same **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operation, the logic to calculate the count aggregate i.e. the number of documents in each category group is done using the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** accumulator operator. The expression `{ $sum : 1 }` returns the sum of values of the number of documents in each group.

To understand the pipeline, run the operation at this stage and analyse the results. So, executing the equivalent mongo operation

```
db.getCollection('shops').aggregate([
    { "$match": { "ShopId": 435 } }, // Step 1
    { "$unwind": "$products" }, // Step 2
    { // Step 3
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$products.productCategory",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "products": { 
                "$push": {
                    "productName": "$products.productName"
                }
            }
        }
    } 
])
```

yields the following documents

```
[
    {
        "_id" : "meals",
        "count" : 2,
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "productName" : "non veg"
            }, 
            {
                "productName" : "non veg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : "juice",
        "count" : 1,
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "productName" : "apple"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : "biriyani",
        "count" : 2,
        "products" : [ 
            {
                "productName" : "non veg"
            }, 
            {
                "productName" : "non veg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Step 4)** The last **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline will then produce the desired result when you specify an _id value of null to calculate accumulated values for all the input documents above as a whole. The desired structure has a `productsList` array that can be created using the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** operator.

Again, running the final aggregate pipeline at this stage will give you the desired result, i.e. executing this in mongo shell

```
db.getCollection('shops').aggregate([
    { "$match": { "ShopId": 435 } }, // Step 1
    { "$unwind": "$products" }, // Step 2
    { // Step 3
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$products.productCategory",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "products": { 
                "$push": {
                    "productName": "$products.productName"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { // Step 4
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,            
            "productList": { 
                "$push": {
                    "categoryname": "$_id",
                    "productcount": "$count",
                    "products": "$products"
                }
            }
        }
    }     
])
```

will yield

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "productList" : [ 
        {
            "categoryname" : "meals",
            "productcount" : 2,
            "products" : [ 
                {
                    "productName" : "non veg"
                }, 
                {
                    "productName" : "non veg"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "categoryname" : "juice",
            "productcount" : 1,
            "products" : [ 
                {
                    "productName" : "apple"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "categoryname" : "biriyani",
            "productcount" : 2,
            "products" : [ 
                {
                    "productName" : "non veg"
                }, 
                {
                    "productName" : "non veg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

One thing to note here is when executing a pipeline, MongoDB pipes operators into each other. "Pipe" here takes the Linux meaning: the output of an operator becomes the input of the following operator. The result of each operator is a new collection of documents. So Mongo executes the above pipeline as follows:

```
collection | $match | $unwind | $group | $group => result
```

Comment: i am new to mongodb and i have few doubts... can u clear that?

Comment: Sure, let me know your concerns

Comment: what is the real purpose of unwind?

Comment: why we are giving 1 after $sum?

Comment: My apologies for assuming your knowledge of the pipeline operators based on your current code. I will try my best to explain each pipeline in detail with an edit to the answer.